# How can i check if a character is in a range of characters?

Tags: php, range, character

I have a character and i need to check if it is in a given range, i.e. between 'A' and 'F'.

Of course i could do

```
if ($c == 'A' || $c == 'B' || ..)
```

but it is terrible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use ASCII code with less than and greater than sign for this

Comment: `if (in_array($c, range('A', 'F')))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ord()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to get the ordinal ASCII character code:

```
if (ord($c) >= ord('A') && ord($c) <= ord('F')) {
    echo "Character is in range."
}
```

Note that this is only "uppercase A through uppercase F". For case-insensitive, use `strtoupper($c)` where you see `$c`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the answer so the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the character to its ordinal value and check its integer range. Such as `if (ord($c) >= ord('A') && ord($c) <= ord('F'))`